# SML polymorphic pattern matching

Tags: polymorphism, sml

I have this

```
fun my_eq (x:'a,y:'a) = true
  | my_eq (x:'a,y:'b) = false
```

which doesn't work. But why not? What I'm guessing is, yes, it might see `x` is, say, an `int` and `y` is an `int` too, but not what the actual values are. Is that why? Is there some way I could have a polymorphic comparison function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types are purely static in typical functional languages, and their only purpose is type checking, not influencing computation.

This is a feature, and actually a very fundamental one. It boils down to a property known as *parametricity* in programming language theory. Roughly, that means that evaluation should never depend on types that are variables at compile time. That is, a program cannot inspect a value when it does not know its concrete type statically.

Why is that good? It gives much stronger invariants about programs. For example, you know from the type alone that `'a -> 'a` has to be the identity function (or diverges/throws). Similar "free theorems" apply to many other polymorphic functions. Parametricity also is the basis for advanced type-based abstraction techniques where you can guarantee that an "untrusted" function cannot mess with the internals of some value or state given to it.

And parametricity is the basis for efficient implementation. A program does not have to pass around costly type information at run time (*type erasure*). Moreover, a compiler can reuse the same representation for values of different types. As an example of the latter, in most SML implementations, `0` and `false` and `()` and `[]` and `None` and the first flat constructor of any datatype are all represented by a 0 word at runtime. This wouldn't be possible if a function like yours was allowed.